# SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence licensing

Tags: sql-server-2012, business-intelligence, ssdt

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Entreprise Edition license, What are the tools needed to work on SSIS/SSAS/SSRS?

Since BIDS was replaced with SSDT on the 2012 version, does it mean I will need to get a separate license and install Visual Studio then get the free SSDT add-in?

Sorry for the confusion, I am new to Microsoft BI and can't find relevant information onlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have to buy a VS licence to use SSDT or SSDT-BI, you have the licence for the services (IS, AS, RS) if you have a SQL Server licence. SSDT and SSDT-BI are just tools to use those services.

You can freely download SSDT and SSDT-BI from Microsoft:

- SSDT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027 (for SQL Server Database projects)
- SSDT-BI: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843 (for SSIS, SSAS and SSRS projects)

**Edit** It is not required to preinstall any kind of VS, the will install the VS Shell if it is not installed.

**Note** You can install BIDS/SSDT-BI using the SQL Server installer, but it contains the version which was available when the installer built (mostly hardly outdated).

Comment: but in both links it says SSDT for VS, does it mean I have to install VS first?

Comment: No, it will install the VS Shell (the core of the VS). You do not have to install any kind of VS. (You can install BIDS/SSDT-BI using the SQL Server install too)